# Linear Algebra - Proof trace equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem :

Let $A_{nxn}, B_{nxn}$ and $X=AB-BA$.

Proof that : $$x_{11}+x_{22}+...+x_{nn}=0$$

**My answer (I don't think its true):**

We know that for $AB$

$$AB_{11}=[a_{11}*b_{11}]+..+[a_{1n}*b_{n1}] 
\\
AB_{22}=[a_{21}*b_{12}]+..+[a_{2n}*b_{n2}]
\\
....
\\
AB_{nn}=[a_{n1}*b_{1n}]+...+[a_{nn}*b_{nn}]
$$

and for $BA$

$$BA_{11}=[b_{11}*a_{11}]+..+[b_{1n}*a_{n1}] 
\\
BA_{22}=[b_{21}*a_{12}]+..+[b_{2n}*a_{n2}]
\\
....
\\
BA_{nn}=[b_{n1}*a_{1n}]+...+[b_{nn}*a_{nn}]
$$

So we get :

$$AB_{11}-BA_{11}=0
\\
....
\\
AB_{nn}-BA_{nn}=0
$$

Therefore $trX=0$

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB_{11} - BA_{11} = 0$ is not true. Think of $A_{12} = 1$ and $A_{ij} = 0$ elsewhere; and $B_{21} = 1$ and $B_{ij} = 0$ elsewhere. Then $AB_{11} = 1$ and $BA_{11} = 0$.

But it is close. In fact after your expansion it almost requires no effort to obtain $tr(X) = 0$. Just observe that if you sum $AB_{kk}$ and $BA_{kk}$ over $k$, there are $n^2$ terms in each of the sum. Moreover, the terms are the same up to the order of the sum, and therefore the two sums are really equal by the commutativity of addition. In fact, we can see that the terms in the first row of the sum of $AB_{kk}$ over $k$, which is $AB_{11}$, is just the ones which appear in the first column of the sum of $BA_{kk}$ over $k$.

Answer (score 2):

There exist three properities of the Trace:

1. $\operatorname{tr}\left( A+B \right)=\operatorname{tr}\left( A \right)+\operatorname{tr}\left( B \right)$
2. $\operatorname{tr}\left( rA \right)=r\left( \operatorname{tr}\left( A \right) \right)$
3. $ \operatorname{tr}\left( AB \right)=\operatorname{tr}\left( BA \right)$

If you know that, you can do it more directly. If don't, you can proof (is more easy), and then use it. In the incise (2) you can take $r = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show first that the trace is a linear map from $\mathbb{F}^n$ into $\mathbb{F}$, and then show that the trace of $AB$ is equal to the trace of $BA$. These are both not too hard to prove.